# Due to SFDX update unable to convert and deploy scratch org code

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

After updating **sfdx cli** to **1.77.1** unable to convert and deploy the scratch code org in packaging org.

**Old Convert Command:** 
`sfdx force:source:convert --outputdir '/Users/mack/Documents/outputdir' --packagename "My Package"` 
 **earlier Deploy Command to packaging Org:** 
`sfdx force:mdapi:deploy --deploydir '/Users/mack/Documents/outputdir' --targetusername "myOrg@pkg.com"`

**New SF Convert Command:** 
`sf project convert mdapi --root-dir '/Users/mack/Documents/rootDir' --output-dir '/Users/mack/Documents/outputDir'`
**or**
`sf project convert source --root-dir '/Users/mack/Documents/rootDir' --output-dir '/Users/mack/Documents/outputDir' --package-name 'My Package'`

**After using the new sf convert command it's not converting the object and labels etc etc.**

Could anyone help to find the correct command for converting and deploying?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're converting to "mdapi form" and using the metadata api to deploy instead of keeping things in "source form" and using `sf deploy`? Keeping things in source form should make your life easier.

Comment: Hi @DerekF
I'm developing an AppExchange product, so after the development, I need to deploy the code from scratch org to packaging org. 
Due to this, I was doing the conversion.

Comment: Derek's point is that `package deploy start` works on all orgs. There's no need to use `mdapi` commands to constantly convert your source. Why specifically do you feel you need `mdapi` format?

Comment: I got your point. what is the command to deploy in packaging org?

Comment: If you are working on an AppExchange product, you should use Packaging V2, much easier to handle that PackagingV1, because you generate package versions directly from the files using sfdx. If you already have a V1 package, you can read this article -> https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2023/05/move-to-managed-2gp-with-package-migrations